# Pandas and confusion over passing by value and passing by reference

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

A function returns a Pandas DataFrame. I try to create a new DataFrame with "newFrame = myFunction()". But the newFrame variable acts more like a reference than a distinct object. Can you help?

In these snippets, FrameMaker.py updates a DataFrame object on a timer. It has a function get_frame that returns that DataFrame object.

Multiple scripts call that function to get a copy of the DataFrame. GetFrameData.py is an example. It calls the get_frame function and assigns the returned value to a variable. It should then have its own copy of the DataFrame, and anything it does to its copy of the DataFrame should have no effect on any other copies.

But it does cause an effect. GetFrameData.py drops columns from the DataFrame. The first time that runs, the "values.drop" line runs successfully. The second time it runs, it gives an error that the DataFrame doesn't have the columns in question. It's like the 'values' variable is a reference to the DataFrame in FrameMaker.py, not a distinct object in the GetFrameData stack. Kind of like how Strings function in most languages.

How should I change my code to get a *copy* of the DataFrame object, not a *reference*?

```
FrameMaker.py

def update_frame(myFrame):
    #Code to remove old rows and add new rows to myFrame
    return myFrame

#Initialize the myFrame object
myFrame = update_frame(pd.DataFrame(columns = ['timestampx','length','dscp','srcip','destip']))

#Code to run "myFrame = update_frame(myFrame)" on a timer.

def get_frame:
    return myFrame
```

```
GetFrameData.py

from FrameMaker import get_frame

#I think this creates a reference to the same object referenced by myFrame. How do I create a new DataFrame object with myFrame's contents?
newFrame = get_frame() 

#This line affects the object referenced by myFrame in Framemaker.py. I don't want that.
newFrame.drop(['dscp','srcip','destip'], 1, inplace=True) 

print(values.head)
```

Comment: Don't use `inplace` and use `droppedFrame = newFrame.drop(...)`? I'm not sure since you've commented out a bunch of lines of code in `update_frame` but somewhere in there is probably also a chance to make a copy of the frame instead of updating `myFrame`.

Comment: Thanks. Taking out inpace and creating a new frame works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.copy()`. It copies the dataframe.

```py
FrameMaker.py

def update_frame(myFrame):
    #Code to remove old rows and add new rows to myFrame
    return myFrame

#Initialize the myFrame object
myFrame = update_frame(pd.DataFrame(columns = ['timestampx','length','dscp','srcip','destip']))

#Code to run "myFrame = update_frame(myFrame)" on a timer.

def get_frame:
    return myFrame.copy() # Copy the DF instead of returning the same reference
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding a simple .copy(), as you described, fixed me issue with a minimum amount of change to my code. I appreciate it.